# Slim::Parser::SyntaxError Expected attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I am getting the error `Slim::Parser::SyntaxError at /conversations Expected attribute` when I change `a href="#"` to `link_to [:trash, conversation], method: :post do`.

This is for the delete checkbox to have a action. When in ERB I was using  `<%= link_to 'Move to trash', [:trash, conversation], method: :post%>`

How can I fix this error?

view.html.slim:

```
ul.right
  li
    link_to [:trash, conversation], method: :post do
      img alt="" src="/assets/del_icon.png" /
  li
    input type="checkbox" class='select_conversations'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
= link_to 'Move to trash', [:trash, conversation], method: :post
```

Comment: Yikes. I never realized I left that out lol. That's embarrassing! Thanks!